# How to install Python 3.10 on the base enviornment of Anaconda?

Tags: installation, anaconda, python-3.9, python-3.10

I have python 3.9 installed in the anaconda base environment and have trouble installing the latest 3.10 version. I have tried to use "conda install -c conda-forge python=3.10" but it does not help resolve my problem. Over half a day, I have iteratively applied the command in the terminal but the package would not be installed. Any suggestion?

I've tried to use "conda install -c conda-forge python=3.10" and it did not work. My software still is Python 3.9 and I cannot apply the latest python version there.

Comment: Does it have to target the base environment? A simple fix is to create a new environment with `conda create -c conda-forge -n env python=3.10`

Comment: Thank you Jelphy. I tried to use this method but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda currently doesn't support versions higher than 3.9.

You can create your own environment using your IDE that utilize Python 3.11 and install all the required libraries via pip install from the command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda now supports python 3.10 you can create the env using

`conda create --name myenv python=3.10`